# Running a method in BackGroundWorker and Showing ProgressBar

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, progress-bar, backgroundworker

What I want is when some method is doing some task UI keeps itself active and I want to show the progress of the work in a progress-bar.

I have a method, a `BackGroundWorker` and a `Progressbar`. I want to call the method when `BackGroundWorker` starts running and show the progress. The method contains a loop. So, it can report the progress.

So, what can be done?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'dataSet1.TBLMARKET' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    myBGWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
}

private void myBGWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    parseFiles();
}

private void myBGWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    myProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void myBGWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Done");
}

private void parseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myBGWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

public void parseFiles()
{
  for()
  {
     //parsing
     myBGWorker.ReportProgress(...);
  }
}
```

But it's not working. The `Progressbar` is not updating. Only a small progress is showing after the `MessageBox` "Done".

Comment: Is your parseFiles function calling `ReportProgress`?

Comment: Yes. It's there. Sorry I forgot to add it previously.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as **Not Reproducible or Caused by a Typo** based on the self answer by the author - "*Actually the code works fine. It was not showing the `Progressbar` as the argument in `myBGWorker.ReportProgress()` was fraction and not percentage. So, it was not showing it.*"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Instead of using one ParseFiles method (which should depend on myBGWorker) use loop and method which parse one file. Report progress percentage in that loop:

```
private void parseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    parseButton.Enabled = false;
    myBGWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void myBGWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < filesCount; i++)
   {  
       ParseSingleFile(); // pass filename here
       int percentage = (i + 1) * 100 / filesCount;
       myBGWorker.ReportProgress(percentage);
   }
}

void myBGWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    myProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

void myBGWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    parseButton.Enabled = true;
    MessageBox.Show("Done");
}
```

Comment: Can you please comment how to deactivate the button when the BackGroundWorker is running. Otherwise there would be problem.

Comment: @soham.m17 sure, just set `parseButton.Enabled` property when starting parsing, and when parsing completed

Comment: But it's in different Thread. So it should throw an exception there in `RunWorkerCompleted` eventHandler. But it's not throwing? May I know why?

Comment: RunWorkerCompleted and ProgressChanged event handlers are executed on UI thread, so don't worry. If you have some errors during parsing, then check `e.Error` property of completed event handler argument.

Comment: This still blocks my UI

Comment: Can someone give an example "without" a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code works fine. It was not showing the `Progressbar` as the argument in `myBGWorker.ReportProgress()` was fraction and not percentage. So, it was not showing it.

Answer (score 0):

To. soham.m17
using with sender argument

```
private void myBGWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   var worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
   for(int i = 0; i < filesCount; i++)
   {  
       ParseSingleFile(); // pass filename here
       int percentage = (i + 1) * 100 / filesCount;
       worker.ReportProgress(percentage);  // use not myBGWorker but worker from sender
   }
}
```