# Simple updating label with progress bar

Tags: vb.net, label, progress-bar

I have this code which works with the filepath but I am trying to get it to change the text to "Search completed" once it is done searching. This is what I tried and I tried it without the quotes around 100 but it still isn't working, any pointers.

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim argument = DirectCast(e.Argument, Tuple(Of String, String))
    Dim target = argument.Item1
    Dim folderPath = argument.Item2
    Dim filePaths = IO.Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.txt")

    'Report the total file count.
    Me.BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(filePaths.Length)

    For Each filePath In filePaths
        'Report progress.
        Me.BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(CInt(False), filePath)

        If IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath).Contains(target) Then
            'Report a successful search.
            Me.BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(CInt(True), filePath)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
Private Sub backgroundworker1_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    Dim filePath = DirectCast(e.UserState, String)

    If filePath Is Nothing Then
        'This is the total file count.
        Me.dataprogbar.Maximum = e.ProgressPercentage
    ElseIf CBool(e.ProgressPercentage) Then
        'This is a successful search.
        Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(filePath)
    Else
        'This is a simple progress update.
        Me.dataprogbar.PerformStep()
        Me.Label1.Text = filePath
        If dataprogbar.Value = "100" Then
            Label1.Text = "Search Completed"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So what is the value of `dataprogbar.Value` when you are 'done searching'? I'm guessing it's not 100.

Comment: @TheBlueDog the maximum value is set to 100

Comment: @TheBlueDog I added the whole code so the maximum = e.progresspercentage

Comment: The first comment is probably key - you are not getting to the point where .Value = 100. I'm not sure this is a good way to indicate you are done searching. What do you think CBool(e.ProgessPercentage) is doing? Doesn't make much sense - are you testing for <> 0

Comment: I'll ask again, what is the value of `dataprogbar.Value` when you are 'done searching'? Whatever you have set the maximum value to is irrelevant at this point.

Comment: @TheBlueDog the value should be 100 when done searching, I updated all the backgroundworker code. thanks. Regards Jake.

Comment: "`the value should be 100 when done searching`"
It ***should be***, or ***it is*** = 100?

Comment: @alstonp I don't know what you mean :( I updated the code. It says the value = e.progressprecentage. I am really trying here but I just can't comprehend what you are saying.

Comment: Basically, we're asking did you actually observe the value being 100 at the end of the search?

Comment: Oh okay, yes. It finishes the search with the last text document filepath in the label. @alstonp

Comment: Got ya, I'm writing a sample app now

Comment: The progress bar goes all the way up before it's done, maybe it's switch the name but then switching back to the filepath

Comment: There is the problem then, could you help me with a remedy? This is the only way I know of doing it. @alstonp

Comment: Sorry I was wrong about that, I just realized...

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here, but the commentators are correct, you are not getting to 100. Additionally, the link here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1 will show you how to use a backgroundworker properly. This similar question here will show you how to use the two together: [Running a method in BackGroundWorker and Showing ProgressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874122/running-a-method-in-backgroundworker-and-showing-progressbar)

Comment: Progressbar maxes out before it's done and still don't change the label :/

Comment: Ok so it's saying search completed before it is completing and continues searching even though it says its complete.

Comment: Now it is adding all the textfiles instead of where the search string is located, and still continues to search when search is completed, I appreciate all you help pal.

Comment: Np, and your progress bar won't fill up unless you "reportprogress" as many times as you have your maximum value set to. So if you keep adding the count of ***all the files*** and only update ***on a match*** your never going to fill up the progress bar.

Comment: Also, unless someone else swoops in I'll answer anymore questions when I get home. :)

Comment: Noone else will swoop in trust me, I'll wait cause I don't quite get that, as you gathered I am new to this just testing stuff out.

Comment: let me know when your home @alstonp

Comment: You will need to tell your `BackgroundWorker1_DoWork` method to stop doing work once your threshold is reached.

Comment: One thing I'd recommend, is understanding this website has a "teach a man to fish" mentality, so this link should provide all the answers you need: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: Yeah that didn't help, appreciate your help. I just won't use it