# Displaying Progress Bar while other Parallel Function is Running

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I want to display progress bar when run a function. That progress bar value in change with run it.

I use `background worker`

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
// run function.
}
```

While run function i want to change ProgressBar value.

I want to use `ReportProgress(Int32)` but what Int32 can i set for it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running a method in BackGroundWorker and Showing ProgressBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874122/running-a-method-in-backgroundworker-and-showing-progressbar)

Comment: Thanks, but in DoWork i serach,insert,delete item of DB. i don't have any loop for set value .

Comment: So, please add example of worker_DoWork method if you have no loops, it can be difficult to show progress in communication with db

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you have nothing to track progress of, the best you can do is to increment the progress bar after every line in the method, or have a different percentage complete after every line, depending on what the the line does:

```
public void Method()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(30);
            Console.WriteLine("World");
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(60);
            //Do more work here....
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100);

        }


 private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }
```