# How can i calculate percentages and report them to backgroundworker?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Now i'm reporting each file name i'm searching in and it's working fine.
But now i also want to report the percentages progress to progressBar1 i have in the designer. The calculation should also include if the program enter the while loop. I added a counterFiles variable but not sure how to do it.

I have this method:

```
public List<string> FindLines(string DirName, string TextToSearch)
{
    int countFiles = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    List<string> findLines = new List<string>();
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(DirName);

   if (di != null && di.Exists)
   {
        if (CheckFileForAccess(DirName) == true)
        {
            foreach (FileInfo fi in di.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                if (string.Compare(fi.Extension, ".cs", true) == 0)
                {
                    countFiles++;
                   //countFiles / 
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, fi.Name);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
                    using (StreamReader sr = fi.OpenText())
                    {
                        string s = "";
                        while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            if (s.Contains(TextToSearch))
                            {
                                counter++;
                                findLines.Add(s);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return findLines;
}
```

In the backgroundworker dowork and progresschanged events

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
        FindLines(@"d:\c-sharp", "string s1 = treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag as string;");
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    label2.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
}
```

Comment: have you tried a google search on progressbar and progressStatus background worker.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874122/running-a-method-in-backgroundworker-and-showing-progressbar

Comment: I know the formula for calculating progress * total / 100 the problem is how do i know the total in my code ? In the link you provided the user know the number of files but how do i find the number of directories in my code as total ?

Comment: there are several projects out there that show what you are looking for there is one on the `CodeProject` site .. do a google search for `C# CodeProject backgroundworker progressbar`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use AJAX in Jquery to do this.

In your cs file:

Declare:

```
    public static int DownloadPercent { get; set; }
```

Then use the Upload method, progress changed method, and complete methods:

```
private void StartDownload(string DownloadSource, string SaveLocation)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
                client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
                client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(DownloadSource), SaveLocation);
            });
            thread.Name = "aFieldDownload";
            thread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            DownloadPercent = 999;
        }
    }
    void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        byteHasBeenDownloaded = true;
        try
        {
            double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
            double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
            double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
            DownloadPercent = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            DownloadPercent = 999;
        }
    }
    void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (byteHasBeenDownloaded)
        {
            DownloadFinishTime = DateTime.Now;
            UpdateActionDuration(false);
        }
    }
```

Then add this method which you will call using AJAX to update the percent:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static int GetDownloadPercentage()
    {
        return DownloadPercent;
    }
```

For the JavaScript, use this as the document loads:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(updateDownProgress, 100);
});
```

Use this JavaScript function as the updater:

```
function updateDownProgress() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Home.aspx/GetDownloadPercentage",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    success: function (msg) {
        $("#cp_MAIN_CONTENT_DownPercentage").text(msg.d + "% DOWNLOADED");
        $("#cp_MAIN_CONTENT_progressBarDown").val(msg.d);
        if (msg.d < 100) {
            setTimeout(updateDownProgress, 100);
            if (msg.d > 0) { $(".StartDownloadButton").prop("disabled", true); }
            else { $(".StartDownloadButton").prop("disabled", false); }
        }
        else if (msg.d > 100) {
            //Use for Error codes
        }
    }
});
}
```

And Finally... Use this HTML for your progress bar:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pDownLoading" CssClass="loading" runat="server">
            <progress id="progressBarDown" runat="server" value="0" max="100"></progress> <asp:Label ID="DownPercentage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </asp:Panel>
```