# YoutubeSearch Nuget in a bgworker and progressbar not working

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

Here is a question very close to mine (I think): [Running a method in BackGroundWorker and Showing ProgressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874122/running-a-method-in-backgroundworker-and-showing-progressbar)

Here is my code, it's not freezing my Main form anymore but the function doesn't do its job.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using YoutubeSearch;


namespace searchyoutubeTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myBGWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        }

        void myBGWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            myProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        void myBGWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            btnSearch.Enabled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Done");


        }


        private void myBGWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            VideoSearch items = new VideoSearch();
            List<Video> list = new List<Video>();
            foreach (var item in items.SearchQuery(txtSearch.Text, 1))
            {
                Video video = new Video();
                video.Title = item.Title;
                video.Author = item.Author;
                video.Url = item.Url;
                byte[] imageBytes = new WebClient().DownloadData(item.Thumbnail);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
                {
                    video.Thumbnail = Image.FromStream(ms);
                }

                list.Add(video);

            }
            e.Result = list;
        }


        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnSearch.Enabled = false;
            myBGWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

            //VideoSearch items = new VideoSearch();
            //List<Video> list = new List<Video>();
            //foreach (var item in items.SearchQuery(txtSearch.Text, 1))
            //{
            //    Video video = new Video();
            //    video.Title = item.Title;
            //    video.Author = item.Author;
            //    video.Url = item.Url;
            //    byte[] imageBytes = new WebClient().DownloadData(item.Thumbnail);
            //    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
            //    {
            //        video.Thumbnail = Image.FromStream(ms);
            //    }

            //    list.Add(video);

            //}
            //videoBindingSource.DataSource = list;
        }

        private void txtSearch_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                btnSearch_Click(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }


    }
}
```

But if I do only the function, it works:

```
 //VideoSearch items = new VideoSearch();
        //List<Video> list = new List<Video>();
        //foreach (var item in items.SearchQuery(txtSearch.Text, 1))
        //{
        //    Video video = new Video();
        //    video.Title = item.Title;
        //    video.Author = item.Author;
        //    video.Url = item.Url;
        //    byte[] imageBytes = new WebClient().DownloadData(item.Thumbnail);
        //    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
        //    {
        //        video.Thumbnail = Image.FromStream(ms);
        //    }

        //    list.Add(video);

        //}
        //videoBindingSource.DataSource = list;
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to register the envent Do_Work using either "+=" or from the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you correctly added the events for the button and onload of the form.
You didnt attach the events for the `BackgroundWorker`. When you click on the searchbutton, the workers starts and the `DoWork` method is invoked on a seperate thread.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    myBGWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    myBGWorker.DoWork += myBGWorker_DoWork;
    myBGWorker.ProgressChanged += myBGWorker_ProgressChanged;
    myBGWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += myBGWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
}
```

Comment: This has solved the problem, Thanks @Sievajet but the DataGridView is not being populated. It just shows the "Done" message at the end. I know this should be another problem, but if you could just help me with this last one, appreciate it. I think the problem is the part `e.Result = list;` because the code in the normal(without the myBGWorker)  is `videoBindingSource.DataSource = list;` . How do I go about the return of the `DoWork`. And oh! the myProgressBar doesn't animate marquee. Thanks in advanced everyone.

Comment: In the `DoWork` you only set the e.Result with the result from your process.  In the `RunWorkerCompleted` event you should do something like `videoBindingSource.DataSource = e.Result` To fill the grid.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much @Sievajet. I did like this `list.Add(video);` 
                `e.Result = list;` About the myProgressBar, I added these to DoWork `myProgressBar.Value = myProgressBar.Minimum;` `int progressCounter = 0;` and inside foreach `progressCounter = progressCounter + 1;`
                `myBGWorker.ReportProgress(progressCounter);`  but the progressbar finishes only on 1/3. Sorry, if it's not allowed to ask 3 questions at a time, it's ok if you don't answer. Thanks

Comment: Check you minimum and maximum value. and check whether you increment correctly. at the completion of your process the progress should have the maximum value.

Comment: Hi @Sievajet, Thank you for your time and help. I've put these on the RunWorkerCompleted: `myProgressBar.Value = myProgressBar.Maximum;` `myProgressBar.Size = myProgressBar.MaximumSize;` but still not reflecting. :)

Comment: Hi @Sievajet, you've lost me there. I didn't find any `myProgressBar.MaximumValue`. Sorry for being noob :)

Comment: `myProgressBar.Maximum`