# Move file and folder with progress bar in c# window form

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

Sir i want to move folder and file with progress bar in c# window form. kindly anybody give me helpful material.

[image: MOVE IMAGE HERE]

Comment: What do you mean with move folder and file?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example?* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: @Mikev i am actually going to make File Explorer. and to move file from one directory to another i want to do with progressbar

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you will need to use RunWorkerAsync.

RunWorkerAsync starts an execution of a background operation. ( copy files etc..)

You will need to connect your progressbar with this method.

Check this answer to have a practic example:

[Running a method in BackGroundWorker and Showing ProgressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874122/running-a-method-in-backgroundworker-and-showing-progressbar/13874504#13874504)