# How to track the File.Copy() in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, progress, file-copying

I have a very large file in GBs. I am using File.Copy() function in C# win Form (not a WPF).

But the form is hanging as the process if working on the copying of the file. I was looking for a solution that will help me track the progress of the File.Copy(). But I do not want to complicate the progress with customized stuff.

Please suggest me what I can do. I am new to Forms and C#. I hope I will get a solution.

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044629/file-copy-with-progress-bar) help you with your task?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882686/asynchronous-file-copy-move-in-c-sharp

Comment: But I want use File.Copy(). I do not want to customize things and make it complicated. As the file should remain intact and through any process it will loose it. Please help me.

Comment: it  is byte file

Comment: *But I want use File.Copy().* so you can't customize this

Comment: yes i cannot. so i look for solution

Comment: @RandRandom it is good suggestion. but what if I want to show progress?

Comment: Any solution guys?

Comment: In the first comment.

Comment: There is no "take the simplest class and do something more complex" solution. There normally never is. You need to use a class that can do that like a Filestream.

Comment: I tried the first comment answer. It is copying the file successfully but not showing any progress? Please guide me.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6055385/4948889. I have called the `object.copy()`. Had I done it right or what I missed?

Comment: @JafferWilson do not use the accepted solution. Use [the second one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19755317/2748412). It actually use the implemented framework. It does fire a progress change event. You just have to attach to it and show whatever you want with it.

Comment: @JafferWilson have you read the solution correctly and done what is said there. Especially have you done what is said in the sentence **after** the code?

Comment: @Ralf Yes. but I am not understand what is the issue I cannot see the progress bar.

Comment: @Ralf What is the meaning of subscribe in that solution? Is it like calling the fuction?

Comment: @JafferWilson You now what a delegate is?

Comment: @Ralf I do not know that .. I will read. But what it has to do with the word subscribe?

Comment: You will now the answer when you now what a delegate is. You are missing to many things knowledge wise so i would advise to not use any code found on the internet until you understand basic language stuff used in it.

Comment: You can use something similar to the accepted answer in [File Copy with Progress Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6044629/7444103), but using the Task method shown in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36925751/7444103), passing a [Progress<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) object to update the UI each time a calculated amount of file chunks has been copied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an excellent idea. Why can you just use the windows Copy Dialog?
Just add a reference:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic
```

And use the code:

```
try
  {
    FileSystem.CopyFile(source_path, destination_path, UIOption.AllDialogs);
  } 

catch (Exception ext)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ext.Message);
   }
```

I guess this will help.

Comment: Wow.. this is a great idea. I will try this.

Comment: It is working.. Thank you. I am accepting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your form hanging, because UI stuff (like updating form content, responding to events, moving window, etc) is executed in main thread (so-called STA thread).
In order to not hang UI while executing some operation, you should create another thread for your long-running operation. There are a lot of ways to do it, but the simplest will be to use TPL's Task.Run:

```cs
void Click(object sender, EventArgs args) 
{
   Task.Run(CopyFile);
}

void CopyFile() 
{
   File.Copy(this.src, this.target);
   // note that since we're in different thread, we cannot interact with UI,
   // so you have to dispatch your operations to UI thread. That can be done just using 
   // Control's Invoke method
   this.Invoke(NotifySuccess);
}
```

As for displaying progress, it's will be a bit more complicated. Since File.Copy() doesn't support progress reporting, you have to use FileStreams. You can check example for it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6055385/2223729

Comment: Thanks .. But not the exact solution I am looking for. But a good attempt is appreciated.

Comment: @JafferWilson of course, feel free to investigate further, but you'll find that unfortunatelly there is no way to use `File.Copy` and be able to report copy progress.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a BackgroundWorker to accomplish this task.

You can also create your own form and show progress in real-time by this way.

This way, you don't need to use the windows default dialog.

Use these two links for reference. Also, lots of material is available on Google so there shouldn't be any problem.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2qQgctSi4iY

[Running a method in BackGroundWorker and Showing ProgressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874122/running-a-method-in-backgroundworker-and-showing-progressbar)